# Remote Assist behaving like Remote Desktop with XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, remote-desktop

A few of our support guys (who have XP Service Pack 3) have noticed that when they Remote Assist to certain computers, instead of Remote Assist sending an assistance request, the RA window opens a 'normal' Remote Desktop session inside it, presenting a login window.

It doesn't happen with all remote machines, but if we find one, it happens for every techie who has SP3, every time. The remote machine *does not* have to have SP3.

Copying the mstsc.exe and mstscax.dll from an SP2 machine to the SP3 machine fixes the problem...

Comment: So let me get this straight - although you're (obviously) not using IE8 in any way to initiate the RA session, machines that have IE8 installed are popping up an MSTSC connection session rather than RA?

Comment: Kind of. RA opens, but presents a login screen inside it. I can type my u/n and password into the box, and it will log the current user out.

Comment: OK, gotta make an edit. SP3 is the culprit, not IE8. Machines with SP2 appear to work fine.

Comment: And you're opening RA via MSRA.exe?

Comment: Via this URL: hcp://CN=Microsoft%20Corporation,L=Redmond,S=Washington,C=US/Remote%20Assistance/Escalation/unsolicited/unsolicitedrcui.htm

Comment: What happens if you open MSRA.exe, Offer to Help Someone, enter hostname ??

Comment: I'm pretty sure MSRA is the Vista exe for remote assist. I certainly can't find it on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - got it. It's a known issue, with a hotfix:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957070